# TYPO3 TypoScript hide if equal

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I try to show end_date only if it's different to start_date. With this code end_date is always hide.

```
temp.title = COA
temp.title {
    10 = RECORDS
    10 {
        source = {GP:tx_myextension_event|event}
        source.insertData = 1
        tables = tx_myextension_domain_model_event
        conf.tx_myextension_domain_model_event = TEXT
        conf.tx_myextension_domain_model_event {
            if.field = end_date
            if.equals.field = start_date
            if.negate = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
temp.title = COA
temp.title {
    ...
    40 = RECORDS
    40 {
        source = {GP:tx_myextension_event|event}
        source.insertData = 1
        tables = tx_myextension_domain_model_event
        conf.tx_myextension_domain_model_event = TEXT
        conf.tx_myextension_domain_model_event {
            field = end_date
            if.value.field = end_date
            if.isLessThan.field = start_date
            strftime = %d.%m.%Y
        }
        stdWrap.noTrimWrap = | - ||
        stdWrap.required = 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the end_date, you need this:

```
temp.title = COA 
temp.title {
    10 = RECORDS
    10 {
        source = {GP:tx_myextension_event|event}
        source.insertData = 1
        # Parse data to integer
        source.intval = 1
        tables = tx_myextension_domain_model_event
        conf.tx_myextension_domain_model_event = TEXT
        conf.tx_myextension_domain_model_event {
            # You need this to show the end_date
            field = end_date
            if.equals.field = start_date
            if.field = end_date
            if.negate = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my example I compare two timestamps. With `source.intval = 1` then `end_date`is always removed. If I remove `source.intval = 1` then `end_date` is always shown.